# Combine two audio files together and play them in iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, avaudiorecorder

I do not want any code but want to get a reference about my question mentioned below...

There is background music available and there is recording option in my app...

Once I start recording , application records my sound and when play button clicks , It will play the recording along with the background music...

I had use this [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1667603/mixing-audio-on-the-iphone) but can not get as I want...

I think there is a mechanism like merging two audio files and make it one before playing....

How can I achieve this by coding... Is there any reference link or any sample code available?

Thnx in advance...

Comment: Check this  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5627590/how-to-play-combined-sound-as-if-emanating-from-a-crowd-of-sound-producing-object

Comment: @Jhaliya Thnx but this is not useful for me... as I am new in this technology,do not get things what they told....

Comment: Actually it is, but you have to read between the lines. Let me post it more clearly.

Comment: @MehulMistri hv get any success in it iam working on same thing can u help me???

Comment: @Mehul can you solve this issues..

Answer (score 2):

Most people mistake the one instance of AVAudioPlayer as the unit that plays the sound directly, but it doesnt. Mixing is done by the OS, not by the instance of AVAudioPlayer.
With other words:
No one says you can't have more then one AVAudioPlayer.

Create one for you background and let it play. Create another instance of AVAudioPlayer for you recorded sound and let it play. Voila

Comment: This will not help..It will create on Recorded sound not along with the backgroud music....Thanks for help...

Comment: AH you want to mix them. Have a look at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5714719/how-to-mix-sound-files-of-different-format-using-ffmpeg